# What does the symbol @ mean in latex

Tags: latex

for example

```
\def\if@nch@mpty#1{\def\temp@a{#1}\ifx\temp@a\@empty}
\def\f@nch@def#1#2{\if@nch@mpty{#2}\f@nch@gbl\def#1{\leavevmode}\else
                                   \f@nch@gbl\def#1{#2\strut}\fi}
```

What does the symbol @  mean in latex

Comment: It doesn’t mean anything actually, it’s just another character in the macro name. It’s just not allowed in normal LaTeX mode, only inside packages (or, more generally, after invoking `\makeatletter`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default in a TeX document, a command (also called a *macro*) can be only named using the letters `[a-zA-Z]` but not symbols such as `@`.

Why is that? Because each character has a [*category code*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16412/153678) (or *catcode*, for short), and by default only `[a-zA-Z]` have the catcode 11 that allows it to be used in a macro. But, amazingly, TeX allows you to change a character's catcode! So at the beginning of `cls`/`sty` files, LaTeX sets the catcode for `@` to catcode 11. Afterward, it resets it back to the default.

LaTeX also includes two commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to easily change the catcode of `@`.

For example:

```
\makeatletter

% This is ok define new command with at character.
\def\command@with@at@character{%
    Command With At Character.%
}

% And you can use it in the pair makeatletter/makeatother
\command@with@at@character

\makeatother

% But you CANNOT use the macro here!!! TeX will try to call \command
% but not \command@with@at@character, because `@` now does not have 
% right catcode.
% \command@with@at@character
```

See [**What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)
to get more information.

About the macro `\catcode`(which can help you to change the character's catcode), you can get more information from [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-activechars).